# dynamically change table size based on browser window

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, css, photoshop, kiosk

I have created a webpage (1440px x 900px) in photoshop and exported it to expression web 4. I chose tables and images "auto-create".  I also have the option to "auto-create" CSS.  It is a kiosk webpage that will be put on a variety of screen sizes. (Using Chrome.exe --kiosk)  Since I don't want to edit the photoshop  page every time a new kiosk is deployed, I am trying to figure out how to make the table automatically change its size and all the images inside it to match the size of the browser window. The table is intended to go top to bottom and left to right and 0 (zero) everything...see below.

leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"

Any ideas on how I can create a webpage that will fill the whole screen no matter what resolution the monitor is and make all the images inside the table resize accordingly and not get all out of whack?

Here is a link to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3eYb8/

Here is photoshops CSS output http://jsfiddle.net/BbXgd/1/

Comment: Images in a table... is this really tabular data that should _be_ in a table?

Comment: I think you should really rework the HTML to be responsive instead of doing this with jQuery.  But, look into the .resize() event in jQuery to get started.

Comment: @theZ - that is how photoshop exports it for me.

Comment: @adeneo - How do I use percentages in CSS with exported photoshop webpages and tables?

Comment: How should I know, I've never "exported" a website from Photoshop before. Sounds like a monumentally flawed idea to me!

Comment: @adeneo - What is your suggestion then on the "Right way" to recode my image?

Answer (score 0):

First of all You need to create a css style sheet. and asign the styles by classer / ID's to the divs.

you can have percentages on your css code to match the screen .

To make a fluid display for different ascpect ratios, you need to define each resolution by using @media screens

here is more info on fluid screen.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/

http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=199